# Show tooltip on Google chart legend even if the word is complete

Tags: google-visualization

The default behavior of the tooltip on google chart's legend is showing only when the word is broken for being too long.

[image]

What I want to do is to always show the tooltip regardless of the word being complete or not. Is this possible?

Comment: You cannot control the display of those tooltips, sorry.

Comment: An old question but is there a way to remove this tool box?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to overwrite the tooltip functionality to display the text. Made an example using jquery, however it also makes tooltips for title and axis ticks, but should be close to what you want:

```
      function myReadyHandler(){
          $('g text').mouseenter(function(e){
              if($(this).text().indexOf('...')!= -1) return;
              $('.charts-tooltip').hide();
              $('body').append('<div style="position: absolute; visibility: visible; left: '+(e.pageX-50)+'px; top: '+(e.pageY+20)+'px;" class="charts-tooltip"><div style="background-color: infobackground; padding: 1px; border: 1px solid infotext; font-size: 14px; margin: 14px; font-family: Arial; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;">'+$(this).text()+'</div></div>');
          })
          $('g').mouseleave(function(e){
              $('.charts-tooltip').hide();
          })
      } 

      google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', myReadyHandler);
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Lwkorqn9/